# HTML 5 Canvas / requestAnimationFrame broken in Safari 7.0?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, safari, requestanimationframe

Can someone tell me why this suddenly isn't working anymore in Safari 7.0? Is it a bug in Safari?

It has been working fine in previous versions of Safari and also works in all other browsers I've tested.

```
(function animloop(time){
    var delta = (time - currentTime) / 1000;

    currentFrame += (delta * fps);

    var frameNum = Math.floor(currentFrame);

    if (frameNum >= totalFrames) {
      currentFrame = frameNum = 0;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animloop);

    drawFrame(ctx, img, 104, 124, frameNum);
    currentTime = time;
})(currentTime);
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XjCYN/

Code taken from this excellent article: http://awardwinningfjords.com/2012/03/08/image-sequences.html

Thanks! :)

Andreas

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I've personally confirmed that you're correct in asserting this is broken in Safari 7 / Mavericks, yet functional in Chrome and pre-Mavericks Safari.

There are numerous bugs related to HTML5 canvas and video elements in Safari 7 / Mavericks, this included.

I have reported a bug to Apple regarding the issues with the video tag and have referenced this stack overflow question as an "Additional Note".

I suggest doing the same over at http://bugreport.apple.com and maybe we can convince Apple to resolve these issues.

In case you want to reference my bug report within yours, the ID in their system is 15363385 -- and here's a copy of the report in a gist: https://gist.github.com/keyvanfatehi/7259921